# Processing: mousePressed () / mouseClicked() ticks too often

Tags: java, eclipse, mouseevent

I made a Whack a Mole style game and I am using the mousePressed() method to whack said moles. The code works fine, only problem is there is kind of a game-breaking exploit that you can do simply by holding down the mouse. Basically instead of clicking the mouse each time you can just hold it down to get each mole. To try and fix this I used mouseClicked() instead - same problem. This is possibly due to the boolean I have in the mousePressed() but I don't know, as I have a similar problem in another game I'm coding where there is no boolean variable. I would like the game to make you have to click each time you want to whack a mole, any solutions? I thought about using a timer instead of troubleshooting with that for like 3 hours I just came here. Thanks - here is the code:

```
package whackmole;

import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PFont;
import processing.core.PImage;
import java.util.Random;


public class WHACKMOLE extends PApplet {

PImage mole;
PImage mallet1;
PImage mallet2;

PFont f;
public int timer;
public int startTime;
public int gameTime;
public int startGameTime;


int score = 0;
Random rnd = new Random();
boolean mouseP = false;
int life = 3;


Mole mole1;
Mole mole2;
Mole mole3;
Mallet mallet;
 enum GameState {
        MENU,
        RUNNING,
        RUNNING2
   }
 static GameState currentState;

public void setup() {
    size(1000, 800);

    currentState = GameState.MENU;
    mole = loadImage("mole.png");
    mole1 = new Mole(mole);
    mole2 = new Mole(mole);
    mole3 = new Mole(mole);
    f = createFont("comic.tff",16,true);
    textFont(f,36);
}

 public void draw() {

        switch(currentState){
        case MENU:
            drawMenu();
            startTime = millis();
            timer = 0;
            life = 3;
            gameTime = millis();
            cursor(CROSS);
            score = 0;
            break;
        case RUNNING:
            drawRunning();
            break;
        case RUNNING2:
            drawRunning2();
            gameTime = millis() - startGameTime;

            break;

        }


    }

public void drawRunning() {
    clear();

    background(50,255,50);

    if(timer < 60000){
    mallet2 = loadImage("mallet2.png");
    timer = millis();



    mole1.drawMole();
    mole1.collision(mallet);
    timer = millis() - startTime;
    mallet1 = loadImage("mallet1.png");
    mallet = new Mallet(mallet1, mouseX, mouseY);

    fill(255,255,255);
    text("Time: " + ((60 - timer / 1000)), 850, 50);

    if (mouseP){
        mallet.drawMallet(mallet2, mouseX, mouseY);
    }
    else {
        mallet.drawMallet(mallet1, mouseX, mouseY);
    }
    if(timer > 60000){
        fill(255,255,255);
        text("Game over!" , 400, 400);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }   
        currentState = GameState.MENU;

    }
    noCursor();
    text("Score: " + score ,25,50);
    }

}

public void drawRunning2() {
clear();
mallet1 = loadImage("mallet1.png");
mallet = new Mallet(mallet1, mouseX, mouseY);


mallet2 = loadImage("mallet2.png");


background(50,255,50);

timer = millis() - startTime;

text("Life: " + life ,25,50);

noCursor();

text("Time: " + (gameTime / 1000), 825, 50);
if(life <= 0){
    mole1.dead = true;
    mole2.dead = true;
    mole3.dead = true;
    text("Game over!" , 400, 400);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }


    currentState = GameState.MENU;
        timer = 0;
        gameTime = 0;
        startGameTime = millis();



}

if (timer < 1800){
    if (!mole1.dead){
        mole1.drawMole();
        mole1.collision(mallet);
    }
    if (!mole3.dead){
        mole3.drawMole();
        mole3.collision(mallet);
    }
    if (!mole2.dead){
        mole2.drawMole();
        mole2.collision(mallet);
    }
    if (mouseP){
        mallet.drawMallet(mallet2, mouseX, mouseY);
    }
    else {
        mallet.drawMallet(mallet1, mouseX, mouseY);
    }
}
else {
    startTime = millis();
    if (!mole1.dead || !mole2.dead || !mole3.dead) {
        life --;
    }
    if (life > 0){
        mole1.dead = false;
        mole2.dead = false;
        mole3.dead = false;

        mole1.xPos = rnd.nextInt(950);
        mole1.yPos = rnd.nextInt(600);
        mole3.xPos = rnd.nextInt(950);
        mole3.yPos = rnd.nextInt(600);
        mole2.xPos = rnd.nextInt(950);
        mole2.yPos = rnd.nextInt(600);



        }




    }
}





public void drawMenu(){
    clear();
    background(142,22,178);

    fill(165, 119, 249);
    rect(250, 150, 500, 200 );
    fill(255,255,255);
    text("Time Mode", 375, 270);
    fill(165, 119, 249);
    rect(250, 450, 500, 200 );
    fill(255,255,255);
    text("Survival Mode", 375, 570);


}

        public void mousePressed()
        {
            mouseP = true;

            if( currentState == GameState.MENU && mouseX > 250 && mouseX < 750 && mouseY > 150 && mouseY < 350){
                currentState = GameState.RUNNING;
            }
            if( currentState == GameState.MENU && mouseX > 250 && mouseX < 750 && mouseY > 450 && mouseY < 650){
                currentState = GameState.RUNNING2;
        }

        }
            public void mouseReleased()
            {
            mouseP = false;
            }



public class Mallet{
    PImage mallet1;
    PImage mallet2;
    float xPos1;
    float yPos1;

    public Mallet(PImage mallet1, float xPos1, float yPos1){

        this.mallet1 = mallet1;
        this.xPos1 = xPos1;
        this.yPos1 = yPos1;
    }

    public void drawMallet(PImage mallet1, float xPos1, float yPos1){
        image(mallet1, xPos1 - 40, yPos1 - 60);
    }
}
public class Mole{
    PImage Mole;
    float xPos;
    float yPos;
    boolean dead = false;

    public Mole(PImage mole){       
        this.Mole = mole;
        this.xPos = rnd.nextInt(950);
        this.yPos = rnd.nextInt(750);
    }


    public void drawMole(){
        if (dead == true) {
            this.xPos = rnd.nextInt(1000 - mole.width / 2);
            this.yPos = rnd.nextInt(800 - mole.height);
            dead = false;
        }
        image(Mole, xPos, yPos);    
    }   

    public void collision(Mallet m){
        if(
                mouseP == true &&
        mouseX > xPos && mouseX < xPos + mole.width && mouseY > yPos && mouseY < yPos + mole.height){
            score ++;
            dead = true;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is resolved?

Answer (score 1):

MouseReleased has advantage from longPress. Since release event will be last event in a mouse click (press, hold, release). You must use

```
 mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
```

instead. This is suitable for your situation.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent)

Answer (score 1):

`mousePressed` called Once after each press and `mouseRelease` called Once after each release. If you set a boolean true on `mousePressed` and false on `mouseReleased` of course actions depend on your mouseP variable will trigger many times until you release your button.

If you want you actions called once per press why dont you just use:

```
mousePressed() {
    if(someKeyIsPressed) {
        // fire hit or whatever you want
    }
}
```

something like this. Actions in `mousePressed` will only executed once per press. `mouseClicked` is called after a pressed - release. It could also work so would the mentioned soulutions by Gaurava Agarwal, but for games doing acions when you release a button is strange an unusual. Imagine an fps game where you shoot when button is released.